# After update to Xcode 11.3.1, getting error "Failed to resolve AuthenticationServices.IASAuthorizationControllerDelegate" in Xamarin Forms iOS project

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

My Xamarin Forms application (built on Windows 10 using Visual Studio 2017, connecting to a remote Mac running Mojave) has been building fine and publishing to both Android and iOS stores for several years.

However after updating my remote Mac's Xcode install to 11.3.1 (to comply with Apple's latest enforcements on app publishing) I'm suddenly getting the mysterious build error:

```
Failed to resolve "AuthenticationServices.IASAuthorizationControllerDelegate" reference from "Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=84e04ff9cfb79065"
```

I've read similar questions posted on this but they're not relevant to my setup, and after spending a full day on this I cannot find a solution - so I'm stumped; can't build on iOS anymore. Does anyone have anything that can shed light on this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lengthy dialogues with both Microsoft and Apple support staff, it required multiple steps to solve this:

- Upgrade Visual Studio 2017 to Visual Studio 2019, with latest patches (released on 2nd June 2020).
- Upgrade remote build server from Mojave to Catalina.
- Upgrade Xcode on the build server to 11.5.

The following quote from Microsoft support sums up the issue I had:
"Building Xamarin iOS applications is not supported with Xcode 11.4, either on VS2017 or VS2019. You must upgrade to Xcode 11.5 (and thus Catalina) to have a bug-free experience with VS2019."

Answer (score 0):

If you updated your XCode, usually you need to update your Visual-Studio too.

The new XCode use the new `iOS sdk` and you need update your visual-studio to use the new `Xamarin.iOS` sdk.

You can also have a try with setting the [Linker Behavior](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/linker?tabs=windows#linker-behavior) to `Link SDK assemblies only`.

I would recommend you to use [Visual Studio 2019](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/vs/) instead of Visaul-Studio 2017.

Comment: Alas we already have the latest updates for VS2017, and already using "Link SDK assemblies only". We'd love to begin using VS2019, but unfortunately it's still an absolute car crash for Xamarin development, so until the stability and bugs get remedied we have no choice but to stay with 2017.

Comment: Which version of Xamarin.iOS are you using?

Comment: Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK: 12.4.0.64 (9c8d8e0)

Comment: The [ASAuthorizationControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/authenticationservices/asauthorizationcontrollerdelegate?language=objc) exist start from iOS 13 and you need to use Xamarin.iOS 13+ in your project. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/13/13.16) is the release note of Xamarin.iOS.

Comment: After reading what you've linked, and after having done some more experiments, the core problem turns out that VS1017 doesn't support Xcode 11.3, however VS2019 also doesn't support it, due to some known bugs Apple have introduced. These bugs do not exist in updates to Xcode, however 11.3 is the last Xcode version supported by MacOS Mojave, so we're stuck in a limbo of not being supported by any of our platforms. I'm going to do some more experiments by downgrading Xcode to just v11, and seeing if that will help.

Comment: VS2019 do support XCode 11.3. See the [requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/release-notes/13/13.16#requirements).

Comment: I don't disagree: that's what the requirements state, however the error messages I see read along the lines of "...Xcode 11.3.1 is not supported in this version of Visual Studio...", so something is clearly still amiss with it. I'm in the process of building a macOS Catalina remote machine, which will allow me to install the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: Xcode 11.3.1 is not supported in this version of Visual Studio means your current version of Visual-Studio is lower than required. You need to update your visual-studio.

Comment: I'm afraid I already have: using Visual Studio 2019, Version 16.5.4, with Xamarin.iOS and Mac SDK 13.16.0.13, reproduced across four Windows 10 machines. This is proving to be a head-scratcher. Still working on getting Xcode 11.4.1 setup on Catalina, however it's taking a while to configure to try some more tests.

Comment: Ok, if the problem still exist after test, you can open a support ticket [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/supportforbusiness/productselection?sapId=211dd84f-3474-c3c5-79bf-66db630c92a6). You can also try the sample [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/platform/ios13/sign-in) which use this api.

Comment: To be honest I think it's an Xcode problem, rather than a VS one. I'm also in conversation with Apple dev support, which is progressing slowly - VS connectivity for Xamarin development is obviously not something they're particularly bothered about.

Comment: Ok, you can share your solution here once you solve it:).